# When do you multiply by the average Big O of nested loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

When do we multiply the Big O of the outer loop by the average Big O of the inner loop?

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2) {
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
     //statement
   }
}
Answer: O(n)
```

In this question, the outer loop is O(log n). Since the inner loop executes some number of times based on 'i', the average Big O is taken. This results in a summation of n + n/2 + n/4 + ... = 2n which is then divided to get the average: O(2n / log n).

Hence O(log n) * O(2n / log n) = O(n).

But then why don't we need to take the average for this question?

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < i * i ; j++){

  }
}
Answer: O(n^3)
```

The outer loop is O(n). The inner loop is O(n^2). But why?

Doesn't the inner loop execute based on a value of 'i' in the outer loop? So why isn't the average taken like the question above? - resulting in something like O(n^2 / n) for the inner loop.

Comment: *"When do we multiply the Big O of the outer loop by the average Big O of the inner loop?"* Never. *"This results in a summation of n + n/2 + n/4 + ... = 2n"* Yes, that is the correct analysis. O(2n) is O(n).

Comment: @user3386109 What do you mean, "never"? The mean is the total divided by the number of iterations, by definition, so it is *always* correct (not but always convenient) to do so.

Comment: @kaya3 You answered your own question. To compute the average, you first need to compute the total. And the total is the answer.

Comment: @user3386109 That is assuming there is never a way to compute the average (or at least, its order in big O notation) without first computing the total. Often, there is; an obvious example would be `for i from 1 to n: for j from 1 to m: ...` where `n` and `m` are independent constants. Another common case is `for i from 1 to n: for j from 1 to i: ...` where the average value of `i` is `n/2` so the inner loop executes on average `O(n)` times.

Comment: No, when the average is trivial to compute, the total is equally trivial to compute. The point is that the average tells you nothing that the total doesn't already tell you. And the average is never easier to compute than the total. Therefore, the student should never be computing (or guessing) the average.

Comment: @kaya3 is taking the average useful only when the inner loop varies each iteration?

Comment: It's useful when computing the average is easier than computing the total. In your first example, it isn't, because the average value of the sequence `n, n/2, n/4, ... 4, 2, 1` is not easier to compute than the total `n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 4 + 2 + 1` is.

Comment: @user3386109 *"when the average is trivial to compute, the total is equally trivial to compute"* - yes, indeed - by multiplying the average by the count. But your comment says we never do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of an algorithm is determined by counting how many operations it performs when executed. For a loop which iterates `k` times, where `m` is the [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) number of operations on each iteration, the total number of operations performed is *always* `total = k * m`, simply because the mean is defined to be `m = total / k`.

It also makes sense to do this in big O notation: if a loop iterates `O(k)` times, and performs a mean of `O(m)` operations on each iteration, then the total number of operations is `O(k * m)`.

The problem is that in your second example, you are not calculating the mean correctly. When you say *"The inner loop is O(n^2)"*, **this is already the mean**; you are considering the number of iterations of the inner loop for **one** iteration of the outer loop. The total number of iterations is `O(n^3)`, and the number of iterations of the outer loop is `n`, so the mean is `O(n^3 / n) = O(n^2)` as expected.

It is more natural to do this calculation the other way around: after observing that the mean is `O(n^2)`, and the outer loop iterates `O(n)` times, the total is `O(n^2 * n) = O(n^3)`.

Comment: can you explain how in the first example, 2n is a result of taking the total in the first code snippet: n + n/2 + n/4 ... because it didn't multiply by the outer loop's O(log n)

Comment: In your first example, you computed the total directly - by adding up the individual parts - not by computing the average first.

Comment: in the second example, 'i' varies through each iteration of the outer loop though. If n = 5, the inner loop would run 0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 times (30 times). If n = 4, the inner loop would run 0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 times (14 times). Is that really O(n^2) though?

Comment: It's a useful fact to know that the mean of `i^k` for `i = 1 to n` is `O(n^k)`. This can be proved formally, but the proof is not trivial, so your intuition is right that we shouldn't just assume it to be true for no reason.

Comment: @kaya3 Isn't the proof just (sum_(i=1..n)i^k)/n ≤ (n*n^k)/n = n^k?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Sure. I mean it's not trivial in the sense that it doesn't immediately follow from a definition.